# notepad++ : Edit different sections of a text document simultaneously

Tags: notepad++, text-editor

Is it possible for Notepad++ edit different sections of a text document simultaneously the same way as word does?

I mean something like :

*http://www.fmsinc.com/free/NewTips/Office/word.asp*

*"Viewing Different Sections of a Document Simultaneously."
To see two sections at the same time, select Window | Split from the Word menu, and the splitter appears. Just click where you want the document split, and then use the splitter bar to resize the sections.Or even easier, grab the splitter bar, which is positioned above the vertical scroll bar. Just drag it to the location where you want the split*

If it is not possible with notepad++, do you know any text editor that can do it?

I'm not meaning multiediting. I mean split the window so yo can see two parts of the same document and you can copy and paste between both parts, or edit both parts simultaneously. Just as you can do with Ms Word.

Resolved!
View->Move/Clone Current Document->Clone to Other View

Thanks to Ken and Paul, thats what I wanted.

In the reference commented by Paul (question 332163), there was this good tip by user232301:
You can also "rotate" your split view from vertical to horizontal by making :
    a right click on the separation line (cursor will change to a double arrow)
    and choose from "Rotate to the left" or "Rotate to the right"

Comment: I'm not meaning multiediting. I mean split the window so yo can see two parts of the same document and you can copy and paste between both parts, or edit both parts simultaneously. Just as you can do with Ms Word.

Comment: View->Move/Clone Current Document->Clone to Other View

Comment: [See this](https://superuser.com/questions/332163/can-i-get-split-screen-in-notepad-like-emacs)

Comment: Thank you Ken, thats what I wanted.
Do you know if the new panel can be shown below the main document instead of at right?

Comment: Thanks to Ken and Paul, thats what I wanted.

In the reference commented by Paul (question 332163), there was this good tip by user232301:
You can also "rotate" your split view from vertical to horizontal by making :
    a right click on the separation line (cursor will change to a double arrow)
    and choose from "Rotate to the left" or "Rotate to the right"

Answer (score 1):

Resolved!

View->Move/Clone Current Document->Clone to Other View

Thanks to Ken and Paul, thats what I wanted.

In the reference commented by Paul (question 332163), there was this good tip by user232301:

You can also "rotate" your split view from vertical to horizontal by making : a right click on the separation line (cursor will change to a double arrow) and choose from "Rotate to the left" or "Rotate to the right"